# Champagne 2 and ee 2.10

Tags: php-errors, champagne, ee2.9.3

So the cartthrob team (aka mighty big robot) have been bought by Vector Media Group read: https://www.vectormediagroup.com/blog/view/vector-acquired-cartthrob-ct-admin/

I can only assume this is why so many of their ee addons have gone untouched for a while as they were getting out of the game.  Hopefully the vector team can bring some life back to some of these great addons.

I updated from 2.7 to 2.10 (big jump).  Champagne gave me some errors here are the fixes I came up with:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loading an entry I would get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Fieldtype::EE_Fieldtype() in
>   ... expressionengine/third_party/champagne/ft.champagne.php on line 47

To fix that go to line 47 and change it from:
parent::EE_Fieldtype();

to

parent::__construct();

Then when I tried to load the module from the modules menu I got this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Cp::set_variable() ...
>   expressionengine/third_party/champagne/mcp.champagne.php on line 64

To fix this I simply commented out line 64.  I don't get the error because line 64 looks valid to me it's not using Cp::set_variable anymore as that was depreciated in EE2.6...anywho, removing the page title fixed the issue for me.

Hope this helps anyone having issues like me.

Comment: Have you been able to find the solution to the extensions error that occurs as well: `Fatal error: Call to a member function get_channels() on null in /mnt/stor2-wc1-dfw1/403647/589639/www.texastejano.com/web/content/admin/expressionengine/third_party/champagne/ext.champagne.php on line 188`